# Using different codecs in opencv

Tags: python, opencv

```
def create_video(image_counter, directory, page_width, page_height):
writer = cv2.VideoWriter()
noviderr = writer.open('test.avi', 0, 0.5, (page_width, page_height))
if not noviderr:
    print 'Error in opening file.'
for i in range(image_counter):
    d = os.path.join(directory, str(i) + '.jpeg')
    ifile = cv2.imread(d)
    writer.write(ifile)
del writer
```

Alright. So, I managed to create a video using the default codec. I tried all kinds of combinations but 0 was the only argument that it accepted. How can I use other codecs like MPEG?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [CV_FOURCC macro of OpenCV](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videowriter-videowriter) with [FOURCC](http://www.fourcc.org/codecs.php) handle of desired codec. An example is given in the linked OpenCV documentation.

Answer (score 0):

It finally worked. This is what I did:

```
    fourcc = cv.CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')
    noviderr = writer.open('test.avi', fourcc, fps, (page_width, page_height))
```